# How To Get The UI Theme Of Sublime Text To NetBeans?

Tags: java, javascript, c, netbeans, sublimetext2

i was wondering if there's any way to get the UI theme of Sublime Text installed or imported to Netbeans as i really like the layout of Sublime Text. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe it is not possible to do that. Those are totally independent applications.

Comment: Probably not without tremendous effort on your end.

Answer (score 0):

which version of netbeans are you using?

you can try the sublime text theme:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53573/sublime-text-theme

Answer (score 0):

**Pick and download a sublime theme that you like:**

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51424/sublime-theme

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55859/sublime-monokai-theme-for-netbeans-8

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53573/sublime-text-theme

1. Make your whole NetBeans UI darkish:

   - **Tools** **>** Plugins **>** Plugins [Available Plugins Tab] **>** (in search type "dark") **>** Select and install "dark Look and feel Theme"
2. Install downloaded sublime theme:

   - **Tools** **>** Options **>** Options [fonts & colors] **>** (Click the "Import" button and select the downloaded sublime theme)

Enjoy your new dark NetBeans look.